# How is this conditional probability calculated?

Tags: probability

This is from a problem set for [MIT's Open Courseware 6.041](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-041-probabilistic-systems-analysis-and-applied-probability-fall-2010/index.htm). The solution below is publicly available as part of the course.

The question is about the independence of the two events "The forecast was that it will not rain" ($D$) and "Victor was carrying an umbrella" ($C$). It makes sense to me that $P(C|D)$ and $P(C)$ are being compared to determine independence—if they are independent, these probabilities are equal. Sheepishly, I don't understand where the third equation comes from in the following solution. Conceptually I get that if Victor is carrying an umbrella after missing the forecast a forecast of no rain may have happened anyway.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In $P(C|D)$, we know that the forecast is no rain, regardless of Victor seeing it. If Victor sees the forecast (with $0.8$ probability), the chance of getting the umbrella is $0$. If he doesn't see the forecast (with $0.2$ probability), the chance of getting the umbrella is $0.5$, and thus you'll have
$$P(C|D)=0.8\times 0+0.2\times0.5$$

Comment: Thanks. I now see the logic of this. Mathematically how might one come up with this equation? I was trying to get there by starting with the relationship between the intersection of C and D and the total probability of D. As it's written, it's kind of like the total probability of C given D.

Comment: Yes, indeed it is. Let $S$ be Victor seeing the forecast, we have the following relation using total probability:$$P(C|D)=P(C|D,S)P(S|D)+P(C|S',D)P(S'|D)$$. Here, $S$ and $D$ are assumed independent, which is quite intuitive.

Comment: That's interesting. It's as if you can start with the equation for $P(C)$ and add that $D$ is given for each term. Sorry to be a stickler, but while it is intuitive that $S$ and $D$ are unconditionally independent, are they conditionally independent? If so then $P(C|D,S) = P(C|S) = 0.0$ and $P(C|S',D) = P(C|S') = 0.5$ and the equation holds. I'm sure the answer is yes and I'll see if I can work that out separately.